# FHIR Validation in Android

Tags: android, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir, caffeine-cache

I have a project in which I have to perform a a FHIR validation. I have implemented this functionality in a regular Java application using the *hapi-fhir* library with the Instance Validator and *Schematron* Validator. I am trying to do the same for android but I have concluded that hapi-fhir using a caching library (*caffeine*) which is not supported in android.

Is there any way I can implement this? Maybe bypass caffeine caching or something I can't think of?

Any suggestions can be very helpful!!

Comment: Have you checked their GitHub page ? There's a dependecy `hapi-fhir-android` [here](https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir/tree/01d6e15f905a344dc0b833c1b0e59808ffea973d/hapi-fhir-android)

Comment: Hello @DavutGürbüz. I have checked the android dependency but I can't figure out if and how I can perform validation in particular.

Comment: I don't wanna direct you to wrong, but what I see [here](https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir/blob/01d6e15f905a344dc0b833c1b0e59808ffea973d/hapi-fhir-android/src/test/java/ca/uhn/fhir/android/client/GenericClientDstu3IT.java)  there is a test case. `ourCtx.getRestfulClientFactory().setServerValidationMode(ServerValidationModeEnum.NEVER);`  inside that factory some validation related methods are implemented, like `newValidator()`  which is returning FHIRValidator. Maybe from the project contributors you can get required help.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. I will look what I can get from this. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

My advice would definitely be to offload any StructureDefinition (i.e profile) validation to a server, e.g. by calling the `$validate` operation.

FHIR's native validation capabilities are really powerful, but they are by their nature very compute-intensive which is always going to be problematic on a mobile device.

For what it's worth, the approach I've seen people take generally is to hand-roll any validation rules on the device that are required for a good UI experience (e.g. mandatory fields and that kind of thing) but then to defer the complex structuredefinition rules until the data hits a server.